filtering date DAX in power BI
Corporate Sale for 2010 = 
var
CorporateDate=filter(DateOne,DateOne[year]=2010)
return 
CorporateDate

When executing this DAX code, this MSG appears:

The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.


That's normal since the code you are using is to return multiple columns, but the context where it is used expects a single scalar value instead.
CorporateDate=filter(DateOne,DateOne[year]=2010) returns all rows from the DateOne table where the year is 2010. This is a table, not a scalar value.
You can use this to directly create a table:
CorporateDate = FILTER(DateOne, DateOne[Year] = 2010)

